# Web browsers (Chromium & Firefox) fail to open in xfce over rdp

Tags: linux, browser, ubuntu-22.04, xfce4, xrdp

I've been attempting to open a web browser on my server with xfce4 over rdp. I've tried chromium and firefox and neither even give an error when opening by clicking on them. I'm using Ubuntu Server 22.04 with xfce4 and xrdp installed.

When running firefox in the terminal I get

> Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
> Error: cannot open display: :10.0

When running it with sudo I get

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/0’: Permission denied
> Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
> Error: cannot open display: :10.0

It'd be really nice to be able to install files directly from the internet onto the server so any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!